# MySQL update column from table B to table A

Tags: mysql, sql

I have big records to copy values from table B to table A. Currently I use:

```
UPDATE table_a, table_b
SET    
table_a.column_a = table_b.column_a,
table_a.column_b = table_b.column_b,
table_a.column_c = table_b.column_c,
table_a.column_d = table_b.column_d,
table_a.column_z = table_b.column_z
WHERE  
table_a.column_uid = table_b.column_uid
```

Current update statement is taking too long to execute because I'm on a notebook. Slow machine.

May I know other way to update these values?

Comment: You want to copy whole table ? or some columns ?

Comment: How big are the tables (how many rows)? Have you tried running the equivalent SELECT against EXPLAIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:  be sure that table A and B both have primary keys or indexes on the column id fields.

Comment: Statement update and both of tables have `pk` as `column_id` and `column_uid` is unique